# Why I cannot delete index directories in Lucene after I make the searcher null?

Tags: java, lucene

I am new to `Lucene` in java. I have met a very strange question:

The service is deployed in `tomcat(struts 2)`. When the service starts, it will create index and searcher instance to provide search service.

Then I want to update the index without stopping the service. So I create another index directory and after this, I make the searchers mentioned before use the new index directory. And then delete the old directory. But problems came here, I cannot delete the old directory. `The message says the directory is still being used by an application.`

**But why? I have switched the index directory and closed the former `indexReader` for searcher. Do I miss anything? The version of `Lucene` is 4.3.**

The error message is as follows:

```
Unable to delete file: D:\Projects\.metadata\.me_tcat\webapps\nlp\WEB-INF\data\index@1392881701\diag\_0.nvd
```

However, I have called `indexReader.close()` and `indexDirectory.close()`.

**BTW, are there any methods to find which thread uses a directory in java?**

I am sorry for my English if it bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually You can't Delete the folder, because when you create a new `IndexWriter` it will lock the folder, and will not allow any other application or service to modify this folder. security issues.

I believe that if you want to delete that's folder you have to say

```
IndexWriter.close();
```

And if you have an opened IndexSearcher on that's folder you also need to say:

```
Directory directory = null;
DirectoryReader ireader = null;
try {
    directory = FSDirectory.open(new File("path"));
    ireader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);

} catch (Exception e) {
//
} finally {
try {
    if(directory != null) {
        directory.close();
    }
    if(ireader != null) {
        ireader.close();
    }
    }catch(IOException e) {
        //
    }
}
```

This will unlock the folder and make it editable.

Comment: Actually, when I finished indexing the documents, I call IndexWriter.close() then init the searcher using the new index folder.

Comment: Then I want to delete the old index folder, there comes the message: "files in the folder is being used by the application". But the searchers is using the new index folder, I don't know why I cannot delete the old one

Comment: You said that when the service starts it will create a new `IndexWriter` and `IndexSearcher`, and then created a new a index folder and want to delete the old one, so you can't delete the old one unless you call `IndexWriter.close()` and `IndexSearcher.close()`

Comment: there is no close method for IndexSearcher in Lucene 4.3 [IndexSearcher](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html). So I don't konw how to release the file handle of the old index folder. This is what bothers me.

Comment: Oh Yes, in `lucene 4.3` they moved the close method to the `Directory` and `DirectoryReader` classes, check my updated answer.

Comment: please see my supplements in the questions(error message), it says the nvd files cannot be deleted yet I have called the `directory.close()` and `ireader.close()`

Comment: Interesting, About 2 years working with lucene i have never seen this error before, any way i think there is a search object still a live, so you need to debug your code.